# How can I integrate BIRT in GWT?

Tags: gwt, charts, reporting, birt

I need to integrate a BIRT chart engine in one of my app. Birt can generate an image as the chart output. My idea is to generate this chart image and then send it to the client side for display. Perhaps in a RemoteServiceServlet on the server. Is this the best way to do it ? or are there other techniques for doing it right ?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most robust way to generate a "report," be it an image, a PDF, or any sequence of bytes that needs to be downloaded by the browser in response to a user action, is to make the client's RPC call return immediately with a URL, or token, at which the contents of the report will be available later.  Later, in this context, just means that a subsequent request will be necessary to retrieve the contents of the report, but the pattern scales well to use cases where it may take a non-trivial amount of time to create the report.

1. The client sends an RPC request to the server with the parameters of the report.
2. The server adds the parameters to a report queue and responds with some token that can be used to retrieve the contents of the report later on.

   - The contents of the report are generated in a separate thread or perhaps on a separate machine if the report is computationally expensive.
   - If the report is guaranteed to only take a short amount of time to complete, it could be generated immediately, but in any case, the contents of the report must be written to a storage mechanism to be retrieved later.
3. (Optionally) The client polls some service to determine if the report is ready.
4. The client presents the report to the user.

   - In your case, the presentation would consist of creating an `Image` widget, perhaps with a URL pattern `http://example.com/getReportImage/<Generated Token>`.  This request could simply block until the report is finished.

If the choice of the report identifier is a function of the report parameters and has stable semantics, you can get caching and de-duplication of work with little extra effort.

As for the choice of using `data:` URLs, it only makes sense if your users are using modern browsers and the image size is tiny.  It's not appropriate for the general case.

Comment: Your idea seems great : I will try it out and let you know about my little experimentations.

Comment: Your idea seems great : I will try it out and let you know about my little experimentations. Actually, I don't need to store the resulting charts because the service that I am about to implement will have to retrieve data from a database to draw the chart. So in order to ensure that data are up to date, IMHO, it's interesting to have it fetching data and dynamically generating the chart.
The only problem that I may have is that, the screen I am working on will have to display more than one chart. Actually, it's a quizz result page having results grouped by "question category"...

Comment: So for example, if one of the app user has responded to 4 Categories, then I will have to generate 4 charts (each for the category). I will probably have some kind of loop doing the **ServiceCall** : Can it be a performance bottleneck ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the client send an RPC and let the server do all BIRT rendering. Once the server has finished, stream the resulting HTML (or image) back to the client. See http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/15515-build-birt-report-engine-with-gwt/

```
myServiceImpl.getReport(
    "monthlySales",
    "2013-02-01",
    "includeGST",
    new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onSuccess(String serverGeneratedBirtHtml) {
            myVerticalPanel.add(new HTML(serverGeneratedBirtHtml));
        }
    }
);
```